Missing control sequence inserted when using `breqn`
I have compatibility problem between my own TeX code and breqn, and I'm out of my depth in my understanding of TeX. I'm encountering this while reviving some LaTeX code from a few years ago. I'm compiling it now on TeXLive 2024.
The following code compiles on TeX and produces a PDF with reasonable content. It extracts the top left entry from a given table and outputs it in math mode.
(There may be easier ways to achieve this particular goal, but this is part of a package and I've stripped the original code down to a minimum working example.)
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{xstring}
%\usepackage{breqn}

\def\rowseparator{\\}%

\def\processtable#1{{%
  \saveexpandmode\expandarg%
  \StrBefore{#1}{\rowseparator}[\firstrow]%
  \restoreexpandmode%
  \edef\tmp{\noexpand\processrow{\firstrow}}\tmp%
}}

\def\processrow#1{{%
  \saveexpandmode\expandarg%
  \StrBefore{#1}{&}[\firstcolumn]%
  \restoreexpandmode%
  $\firstcolumn$
}}

\begin{document}
\processrow{\frac{1}{3} & 1}
\processtable{5 & 1 \\}
\processtable{\frac{1}{3} & 1 \\}
\end{document}

The trouble starts when I uncomment the line \usepackage{breqn}:
! Undefined control sequence.
\genfrac  ...enom =1\relax \edef \mathstyle@tempa 
                                                  {\number \mathstyle }\char...
l.30 \processtable{\frac{1}{3} & 1 \\}

Now, that doesn't seem too bad to fix. Although hacky and (as we'll soon see) probably symptomatic to a bigger problem, adding this at the beginning of the file solves the problem:
\makeatletter
\def\mathstyle@tempa{}
\makeatother

This gets me to the next error:
! Missing control sequence inserted.
<inserted text> 
                \inaccessible 
l.40 \processtable{\frac{1}{3} & 1 \\}

I've spent a few hours trying to nail down what exactly is going wrong, but at this point I'm completely stuck. Notice that only the last line of the main document contents is problematic:
\processrow{\frac{1}{3} & 1}       % works
\processtable{5 & 1 \\}            % works
\processtable{\frac{1}{3} & 1 \\}  % ERROR

Any help debugging this would be highly appreciated :)
EDIT: Thanks to Ulrike, David, and egreg, I sorted it out. I'm happy to share the actual package if there's interest. It is for generating simplex tableaus (for linear programming) like this:


well you are using \expandarg. That means xstring does something like \edef\temp{\frac{1}{3}} and that explodes with breqn. It is not a good idea to fully expand arbitrary user input.

@DavidCarlisle Apparently so, but breqn got changed…

Thank you UlrikeFischer, DavidCarlisle, and egreg. This indeed was the problem, also in my original package.

I'm not sure what your aim is. Anyway, the \edef is the obvious culprit. You just want a one-level expansion of \firstrow.
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{breqn}

\newcommand\rowseparator{\\}

\newcommand\processtable[1]{{%
  \saveexpandmode\expandarg
  \StrBefore{#1}{\rowseparator}[\firstrow]%
  \restoreexpandmode
  \expandafter\processrow\expandafter{\firstrow}%
}}

\newcommand\processrow[1]{{%
  \saveexpandmode\expandarg
  \StrBefore{#1}{&}[\firstcolumn]%
  \restoreexpandmode
  $\firstcolumn$%
}}

\begin{document}

\processrow{\frac{1}{3} & 1}
\processtable{5 & 1 \\}
\processtable{\frac{1}{3} & 1 \\}

\end{document}

Avoid \def!

Thank you! It worked. I've edited my question to explain what this is used for.
